# python: import from relative path

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to import from a folder named template which is structured like

```
controller/
          /__init__.py
          /login.py # <- I'm here
template/
        /__init__.py # from template import *
        /template.py # contains class Template
```

python seems to be able to see the need class but fail to import it, this is login.py code

```
import webapp2

import template

class Login(webapp2.RequestHandler):
#class Login(template.Template):

    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(dir(template))
```

prints

```
['Template', 'Users', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'jinja2', 'os', 'template', 'urllib', 'webapp2']
```

switched import line

```
import webapp2

import template

#class Login(webapp2.RequestHandler):
class Login(template.Template):

    def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(dir(template))
```

prints

```
class Login(template.Template):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Template'
```

what am I doing wrong? thanks

**Edit**: I have created another folder named index which contains

```
index/
     /__init__.py # from index import *
     /index.py # class Index
     /index.html
```

the code inside index.py is

```
from template import Template
class Index(Template):
    def get(self):
        self.render("/index/index.html")
```

this code just worked without any errors, but the one index controller folder fails

Comment: Isn't template the package (directory), which contains the module template (file) which contains the Template class? In this case you want template.template.Template.

Comment: It's not a good idea to create a package with the same name as a module in that package.

Comment: Guy I have made another test case and it just worked, does package name make different?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that when `template/__init__.py` does:

```
from template import *
```

It isn't importing from where you think - it is importing everything from *itself*, since having a folder called 'template' with an `__init__.py` defines a module called 'template' - which gets priority over the module inside it also called 'template'. You need to tell Python explicitly that you want the inner module, which you can do like this:

```
from .template import *
```